# Create new MIDI event

Tags: java, midi, javasound, javax.sound.midi

I have created Java code that plays a sequence from a MIDI file which has one track. I am testing it with a MIDI interface and a hardware synthesizer and everything works fine.

What I want to do now is add new MIDI events to a new track. So for this purpose I have written this code:

```
   Track t= mySeq.createTrack();
   ShortMessage on = new ShortMessage();
   on.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, 36, 90);

    ShortMessage off = new ShortMessage();
    off.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, 36, 90);

    t.add(new MidiEvent(on,(long) 1));
    t.add(new MidiEvent(off,(long) 1000));
```

The new track is created and the MIDI event is in there, but there's no sound coming out. However the newly created event is being send to my midi interface because the "midi out" led is flashing. So I am guessing that although an event is being send it lacks some info?

Do I need to include any more info on my code when creating a new track/ new MIDI event?

Comment: I think we need more information, such as the library you are using and a true [mcve].

Comment: So you get two flashed at the expected times?